# How to remove specific json feed cache in Volley? clear() works, but remove(url) does not work

Tags: java, android, caching, android-volley

I have an adapter for Volley to handle HTTP requests using OKhttp3 as the transport and `DiskBasedCache` as the caching implementation.

I'm trying to remove a specific JSON feed request from the cache by using `.remove(url)` but it isn't working. Here's an example code:

Make a request in an activity:

```
String url = "http://somewebsite.com/feed.json"

VolleyStringRequest stringRequest = new VolleyStringRequest(Method.GET,null, url,responseListener(),errorListener());

RequestQueue queue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue();

queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Remove the cache after something has been done:

```
Cache cache = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue().getCache();

Cache.Entry cacheEntry = cache.get(url);

if (cacheEntry != null) {
     Log.d("cache", "has_cache");
} else {
     Log.d("cache", "no cache");
}

cache.remove(url);
```

However, in the logCat, the key `url` returns "no cache", and the `cache.remove(url)` produces

```
 DiskBasedCache.remove: Could not delete cache entry for key=http://somewebsite.com/feed.json, 
 filename=-159673043453434434
```

Does anyone know how to use `cache.remove(url)`? Does Volley use url as cache entries' keys? I don't want to use `cache.clear()` but just remove a specific request cache.

CustomVolleyRequestQueue :

```
public class CustomVolleyRequestQueue {

    private static CustomVolleyRequestQueue mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private CustomVolleyRequestQueue(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequestQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CustomVolleyRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(mCtx.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new OkHttpStack());
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            // Don't forget to start the volley request queue
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I have made a custom class that extends `DiskBasedCache` to check what key it uses for the cache.

```
public class CustomDiskBasedCache extends DiskBasedCache {

    public CustomDiskBasedCache(File rootDirectory, int maxCacheSizeInBytes) {
        super(rootDirectory, maxCacheSizeInBytes);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void put(String key, Entry entry) {
        super.put( key,  entry);
        Log.d("cache_key",key);
    }
}
```

It looks like every cache key is prefixed with `0:`, for example:

`0:http://somewebsite.com/feed.json`

I don't know why it is added.

Answer (score 1):

about the debug message you see

> Could not delete cache entry for ...

it is because in [DiskBasedCache.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/DiskBasedCache.java) remove(String key) displays debug message when deleting file is unsuccessful the inmemory entry is deleted anyway so the cashe will be gone, while clear() just whatever files are available.

you actually discovered why you have this bacause the file you want to delete is not there.

so you second question why you have this prefix. it is because you probably override

public String getCacheKey() {

in your custom VolleyStringRequest